# Можно ли работать с функцией внутри цикла?

Tags: c

К примеру:

```
k = trololo(x);
for (i=k; k>0; x--)
{
 //что-то выполнялось исходя из значений X
}
```

Как обращаться к функции внутри цикла, чтоб при каждом изменении значения X, происходил запрос в функцию trololo????? Заранее благодарю за помощь)

Comment: А в чем проблема написать `k = trololo(x);` внутри цикла?

Comment: может лучше там где изменяется x вызывать trololo? Или конкретизируйте вопрос, пожалуйста. Хотя в бесконечном цикле постоянно присваивать переменной внутри цикла значение переменной в более глобальной области.

Comment: `for (i = trololo(x); i > 0; i = trololo(x--))`

Answer (score 0):

Можно.Так же как и вне цикла.

https://prog-cpp.ru/c-functions/

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS // для возможности использования scanf
#include <stdio.h>
// Функция вычисления суммы двух чисел
int sum(int x, int y) // в функцию передаются два целых числа
{
  int k = x + y;  // вычисляем сумму чисел и сохраняем в k
  return k;       // возвращаем значение k
}
int main()
{
  int a, r;      // описание двух целых переменных
  printf("a= ");
  scanf("%d", &a); // вводим a
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
     r = sum(a, i);    // вызов функции: x=a, y=5
     printf("%d + i = %d", a, r); // вывод: a + 5 = r
  }
  getchar(); getchar(); // мы использовали scanf(),
  return 0;  // поэтому getchar() вызываем дважжы
}
```